not-found.tsx page in the context of multiple root layout.jsx in Next JS
I hope someone might be able to help.
I have this page structure in my NextJS 14 app:
app/
   (admin)/
          layout.tsx
   (web)/
        layout.tsx
        page.tsx
   
   not-found.tsx


Note that i don't have a layout.tsx page at the app/ folder level, but multiple root layout inside each route group. The problem i encounter is that NextJS throws an exception pointing out that, the not-found.tsx doesn't have a layout.tsx associated to it.
I tried to put the not-found.tsx inside each route group, but it is not detected, each time a route doesn't exist, the app fallback to the default 404 page.
How could i make this work ?

Include a layout.tsx inside the /app folder and it will be used by the not-found.tsx file. See examples Here
app/
   (admin)/
       layout.tsx
   (web)/
       layout.tsx
       page.tsx
   layout.tsx
   not-found.tsx

